# Puppeteer wait for new page after form submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to load a page, submit a form (which takes me to a different URL) and then ideally run something once this new page had loaded. I'm using Node JS, and am generalising my logic into separate files, one of which is `search.js` as per the below:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const createSearch = async (param1) => {
  puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  }).then(async browser => {

    const page = await browser.newPage(term, location)
    await page.goto('https://example.com/')
    await page.waitForSelector('body')

    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const searchForm = document.querySelector('form.searchBar--form')
      searchForm.submit() // this takes me to a new page which I need to wait for and then ideally return something.

      // I've tried adding code here, but it doesn't run...
    }, term, location)

  })
}

exports.createSearch = createSearch
```

I'm then calling my function from my app's entry point...

```js
(async () => {

  // current
  search.createSearch('test')

  // proposed
  search.createSearch('test').then(() => {
    // trigger puppeteer to look at the new page and start running asserts.
  })

})()
```

Unfortunately, due to the form submitting, I'm unsure how I can wait for the new page to load and run a new function? The new URL will be unknown, and different each time, e.g: https://example.com/page20

Comment: firstly, in page.evaluate I use \`\` quotes and then I would make global variables like `window.searchForm = ` and `window.searchForm(whatever)` and all your problems are solved.. oh yea and there's no way to know so `setTimeout(()=>{whateverCodeNext},2000)` for entering stuff after entering a new page

Answer (score 2):

After form submit, you need to wait until the page reloads.  Please add this following the `await page.evaluate()` function call.

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

And then you can perform action you want.

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepeted.